# How does browser treat html page with no html markup?

Tags: html

In a number of introductory videos on html, I saw some instructors just type plain text in a text editor (like "Hello World") with no html markup whatsoever, then save it as an html document and load it in a browser, just to demonstrate how easy it can be to make the browser display what you want. Then they follow their (not-so-smart?) actions with an explanation that "HTML is a little bit more complicated than that".

My question is, what does the browser think when it sees an html document with no html markup? Does it treat it as a plain text document, or as a broken html document? Does it create DOM for it (like a text node)?

Comment: Load such a document in a browser and look at the developer tools to see whether there is a DOM and if so what it looks like.

Comment: Hmm, as far as I can tell it seems to have created html, head and body nodes. So it is an html document, even though it doesn't have any html markup?

Comment: Since the browser can't determine the version of HTML, it will go into [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) where it tries its best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser is expected to handle the document according to the Content-Type header (in HTTP headers), though if there is no such header, browsers need to apply some error recovery and make a guess. Different browsers may act differently.

Interpreted as an HTML document, plain text constitutes the content of the `body` element. The rest of the document structure is implied. The document does not conform to HTML specifications, since the `doctype` declaration is missing (and so is the `title` element, but it’s not required in HTML5), but browsers don’t care.